# Query for rows with specific string or null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables, I need a query in Oracle SQL:

T1:

```
ID (PK)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

T2:

```
Id    T1-ID(FK)     Value
 1     1            apple
 2     2            null
 3     2            null
 4     3            apple
 5     3            null
 6     4            apple
 7     4            orange
 8     4            null
 9     5            orange
 10    5            null
 11    6            orange
 12    6            apple
 13    7            kiwi
 14    8            mango
 15    8            apple
 16    8            null
```

how do I get the rows that have only apple or null or both. The query should not return any rows that have orange, kiwi, mango etc even if that ID has apple or null.

Output:

```
Id    T1-ID(FK)     Value
 1     1            apple
 2     2            null
 3     2            null
 4     3            apple
 5     3            null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t.*
from t2 t
where (t.value = 'apple' or t.value is null)
  and not exists (select 1 
                  from t2 x
                  where x.t1_id = t.t1_id
                    and x.value <> 'apple')
order by t.id;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a9f28/1

Comment: thank you! this works.. not sure why I did not think of the 'not exists' logic!

Comment: I have a question though, in the subquery - why is the join needed? can it not be:  select 1 from t2 x where x.value <> 'apple' ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `sub-query` and `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT *
FROM T2
WHERE `T1-ID` IN
    (SELECT 
        `T1-ID`
    FROM T2 
    GROUP BY `T1-ID`
    HAVING 'apple' = GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Value))
```

Comment: I guess I was not clear in my question earlier, I have updated it now. There may be many other values like orange, so I don't think it is possible to list all of them in the having not condition.